# Book about a girl with purple eyes whose father was a (prince?) alien from a different world

Tags: story-identification, books

Book about a girl with purple eyes whose father was a (prince?) alien from a different world. I think the cover was either a greyscale purple eye or a purple crystal. She met a boy from the other world who was a prince(?). She was hunted by people from the other world as well(?).

Comment: This is a brief description do you remember anything else you could [edit] in? Plot details? When you read it? Etc.

Comment: What year did you read it? Was it old then or new? Where did you read it and in what language? Any extra detail you could give would help so much, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Not a lot to go on, but possibly Ian Irvine's "[A Shadow on the Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Shadow_on_the_Glass)", the first book in "[The View From the Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_View_from_the_Mirror)" quartet.

From the minimal clues provided:

> Book about a girl with purple eyes whose father was a (prince?) alien from a different world.

Check. The protaganist, Karan, had purple eyes signifying she was descended from a Charon, a race from a different world. Her father was, I think, one of that race.

> I think the cover was either a greyscale purple eye or a purple crystal.

No check.

> She met a boy from the other world who was a prince(?).

Half a check. Early on she meets Llian who's neither a prince nor from the other world. They spend most of the series together.

> She was hunted by people from the other world as well

Check. Due to her Charon nature, she was pretty much hunted by everybody

Comment: To extend Moriarty's answer of A Shadow on the Glass, this reminds me more of Maigraith. She is described as having purple irises (indicating Charon descent) and later in the series falls in love with Rulke, mightiest of the surviving Charon. As I recall Karan isn't descended from the Charon (though she is a triune, having blood of three of the four human species).

Comment: @AdamJRichardson aargh! You're right. I had Karan and Maigraith mixed up. In the unlikely event this is the right answer, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete match, but given that the question is a bit terse, still worth putting it into an answer: *Stargazer* (2014) by Melanie Matthews?

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22912473-stargazer):

> Ava is an anomaly. **She has the appearance of the enemy alien race known as Stargazers, with her lavender hair and eyes**, but the human capacity for love and forgiveness. Ava has amnesia—not knowing who she is or where she came from. She rejects that she’s a Stargazer, but she isn’t entirely human either, with the strength to crush a man’s bones. The key to everything lies with the dictator Julius Pallas, who orders her torture and imprisonment inside the doctor-ridden mega-facility known as the Corporation. When the two finally meet, Ava will discover her true identity and her connection to him. He’ll discover how greatly she’s changed, and how her destiny may just ruin his murderous empire.

Check:

- girl, purple eyes, alien-related;
- according to [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1497690090), Ava is a Stargazer princess. Having not read the book, and info on it being scarce, I wouldn't be sure, but it may be due to her having a "royalty" father;
- cover features a purple eye:

[image: purple eye on white cover]

Not sure if checks:

- two of the named boys I could find were John and Victor, but browsing the [Google books extracts](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PhJVCAAAQBAJ) don't seem to yield much about them being alien princes as well;
- she doesn't seem to be hunted, *but* all the men "desires" her in some way, so perhaps it could be qualified as a chase...

---

Found with the Google query `book "purple eyes" alien prince site:goodreads.com` and looking at [the Google Images results](https://www.google.com/search?q=book%20%22purple%20eyes%22%20alien%20prince%20site:goodreads.com&tbm=isch), the cover looked promising as it partly matched.

Answer (score 2):

The Fallen Star by Jessica Sorensen!

Summary from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11051889-the-fallen-star):

> For eighteen year-old Gemma, life has never been normal. Up until recently, she has been incapable of feeling emotion. And when she's around Alex, the gorgeous new guy at school, she can feel electricity that makes her skin buzz. Not to mention the monsters that haunt her nightmares have crossed over into real-life. But with Alex seeming to hate her and secrets popping up everywhere, Gemma's life is turning into a chaotic mess. Things that shouldn't be real suddenly seem to exist. And as her world falls apart, figuring out the secrets of her past becomes a matter of life and death.

A description on a site called Shmoop, explains her connection to a young man named Alex, who reveals to her that he is a Keeper who has actually been sent to protect her".  Gemma also knows next to nothing about her parents.  However, Gemma is different from the world around her.  Shmoop also says, "Gemma feels like she doesn't exactly belong in this world. That's why the stars feel so comforting to her:" and:

> When Alex tells Gemma that she's special because she has a fallen star
> inside of her and is destined to save the world, Gemma is overwhelmed
> but not totally surprised. This actually makes more sense to her than
> her "normal" everyday life. And even though Gemma is scared and
> confused, she knows immediately that he's not pulling her leg—Alex is
> telling the complete truth. She's special, and whether she likes it or
> not, Gemma has to work with the Keepers to try to stop the Death
> Walkers from destroying the world.

[image: cover is a purple eye on a grey background]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please explain how this matches the details of the question.  You should model your answer after the others here that include quotes, cover art, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Book is [*Secret Heir*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/36754125) by MJ Prince

> Since the beginning of time, tales have been told about Eden. But all
>   the stories are wrong.
>
> Running parallel alongside Earth, but never touching, there exists not
>   just a garden, but an entire world of vivid colours and breathtaking
>   beauty where the Seraph reside.
>
> Jazmine has lived in ten different foster homes, in ten different
>   towns and all her life she has felt like she doesn’t belong – not in
>   the trailer park which happens to be foster home number ten, not
>   anywhere on Earth.
>
> After a universe shattering revelation, she discovers why. Far from
>   being the nothing and no one, with no past and no future, that Jazmine
>   had always believed herself to be, she discovers that she is in fact
>   an heir to one of the seven remaining Seraph Dynasties.
>
> She is Jazmine Evenstar, the last heir to the sovereign Evenstar
>   Dynasty.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain what details of this story match the question?

Comment: Can you add some matching details to your answer?

Comment: A quick glance at the blurb doesn't inspire me with confidence that this is the correct answer, nor does the [cover](https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1513455806l/37550975._SY475_.jpg) look anything like the description (albeit she does have purple eyes)