# Book about a girl who has purple eyes and wakes up in an airplane crash

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

So I read this young adult/teen book a few years ago about a 16 year old girl named Sarah(?) who woke up in an airplane crash I think it was(?) and couldn’t remember anything before the crash. She also had purple eyes which were significant but I forgot why? (I forgot a lot from this book, it’s been a while).

She also turned out to not actually be human, (I forgot what she was, I think she was a humanoid?) and so she falls in love with another one of her kind, who was made by an evil scientist who was out to get her for some reason(?).

Comment: possibly related? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208379/book-about-a-girl-with-purple-eyes-whose-father-was-a-prince-alien-from-a-dif/208419#208419

Answer (score 4):

*Unremembered* (2013) by Jessica Brody? The girl is named Seraphina, not Sarah, though the names are close. A couple reviews mention her as "Sera", hence the recollection, I guess.

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00Q37GEMC):

> When Freedom Airlines flight 121 went down over the Pacific Ocean, no one ever expected to find survivors. **Which is why the 16-year-old girl discovered floating among the wreckage - alive - is making headlines across the globe.** Even more strange is that her body is miraculously unharmed and **she has no memories of boarding the plane. She has no memories of her life before the crash. She has no memories period.** No one knows how she survived. No one knows why she wasn't on the passenger manifest. And no one can explain why her DNA and fingerprints can't be found in a single database in the world.
>
> Crippled by a world she doesn't know, plagued by abilities she doesn't understand, and haunted by a looming threat she can't remember, **Seraphina struggles to piece together her forgotten past and discover who she really is**. But with every clue only comes more questions. And she's running out of time to answer them. Her only hope is a strangely alluring boy who claims to know her from before the crash. Who claims they were in love. But can she really trust him?

---

Found with the Google query `sci fi book "purple eyes" sarah plane crash android`.

Comment: Where did the  'android' search term come from?

Comment: @Jontia I assumed if the girl was humanoid, and created by a scientist, she must have been an android. I got lucky though (it was my first query and yielded the result), because it appears it's more about genetics engineering